# mssql 30 minute time intervals beteen 2 datetime

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have below query and i want to get datetime in 30 min intervals between 2 datetime. Basicly I got it, but is limitited and wouln't return al results if the timediff is over 24 hrs.

For example:

```
@DateTime1 = 24/11/2016 18:00:00
@DateTime2 = 25/11/2016 06:00:00
```

Result: (in format "dd-HH:mm")

```
24-18:00
24-18:30
24-19:00
24-19:30
24-20:00
...
...
25-05:00
25-05:30
25-06:00
```

What I've tried.

```
SELECT        number, DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1) AS DateTimeLine, DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1)) AS Days, DATEPART(MONTH, 
DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1)) AS Months, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1)) AS Years, DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(MINUTE,
number, @DateTime1)) AS Hours, DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1)) AS Minute, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1) 
AS DATE) AS Date, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1) AS TIME) AS Time

FROM         master.dbo.spt_values

WHERE        (type = 'P') AND (DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1)) = 30 OR DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1)) = 0) AND (DATEADD(MINUTE, number, @DateTime1) <= @DateTime2)

ORDER BY number
```

Comment: If you find yourself calculating island and gaps over date ranges a lot then I would highly suggest creating a Calendar table. It helps immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a TVF which generates dynamic date/time ranges.  It is faster than a recursive cte, and I think more flexible.  You pass the date range, desired DatePart, and increment.

```
Declare @DateTime1 DateTime = '2016-11-24 18:00:00'
Declare @DateTime2 DateTime = '2016-11-25 06:00:00'

Select Format(RetVal,'dd-HH:mm') from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](@DateTime1,@DateTime2,'MI',30)
```

Returns

```
24-18:00
24-18:30
24-19:00
24-19:30
24-20:00
24-20:30
24-21:00
24-21:30
24-22:00
24-22:30
24-23:00
24-23:30
25-00:00
....
25-04:30
25-05:00
25-05:30
25-06:00
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Comment: @René Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

A tally table is a great way to deal with this type of thing. I keep one in a view to avoid using spt_values.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Then your code becomes really simple too. A small amount of datemath and voila.

```
declare @DateTime1 datetime = '2016/11/24 18:00:00'
    , @DateTime2 datetime = '2016/11/25 06:00:00'

select FORMAT(DATEADD(minute, (t.N - 1) * 30, @DateTime1), 'dd-HH:mm')
from cteTally t
where t.N <= (DATEDIFF(hour, @DateTime1, @DateTime2) * 2) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

using a recursive Common Table Expression [CTE] is one pretty clean method.  For the formatting I am showing `FORMAT()` from SQL-Server 2012+  you may consider using `DATEPART` etc to do it though as `FORMAT()` can have performance impact.

I do agree with @RossBush's comment if you do things like this a lot generating a calendar (dates) and a time dimensions is very helpful for these purposes.

```
DECLARE @DateTime1 DATETIME = '2016/11/24 18:00:00'
DECLARE @DateTime2 DATETIME = '2016/11/25 06:00:00'

;WITH cte30MinIncrements AS (
    SELECT @DateTime1 as DT

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,30,DT)
    FROM
       cte30MinIncrements
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,30,DT) <= @DateTime2
)

SELECT
    *
    ,FORMAT(DT,'dd-HH:mm') as Formated
FROM
    cte30MinIncrements
```

Comment: You have a cte that is basically counting. This appears to be set based but in actuality is not. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: @SeanLange and your point being because it isn't set based it can't possible be performant enough for the OPs purposes?  I never claimed it was set based and this technique is pretty common. For performance purposes and lots of other uses as my answer specified I would suggest using a calendar (date) dimension and a time dimension.

Comment: I never said it can't be performant enough. Loops and cursors can sometimes be performant enough. Many people do not realize that using a recursive cte for counting is really doing the same thing as a cursor. My point in bringing it up is to make sure people understand that. And just because something is common does not mean it is the best way to do it. Cursors are incredibly common for this sort of thing and I would caution those solutions too that they are not the best from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works.

```
declare @DateTime1 DateTime = '2016-11-24 18:00:00'
declare @DateTime2 DateTime = '2016-11-25 18:00:00'

declare @Interval DateTime = @DateTime1
declare @vartmptable table(DT DateTime)

While (@Interval < @DateTime2)
begin
 --select @Interval, FORMAT(@Interval,'dd-HH:mm')
 insert into @vartmptable select @Interval
 set @Interval = DATEADD(mi,30,@Interval)

end

select FORMAT(DT,'dd-HH:mm')  from @vartmptable
```

Comment: Any specific reason?

Comment: Because loops are horribly inefficient. They should be avoided except for a very small set of times. Things like some administration and mail merges are about the only times loops are required.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? You can use variables/ fixed values as necessary.

```
WITH CTE_Numbers
AS (
    SELECT n = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n + 1
    FROM CTE_Numbers
    WHERE n < 100
    )
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(mi, n * 30, '2016/11/03'),'dd-HH:mm')
FROM CTE_Numbers
```

Comment: Be careful here. Using a rcte to count like this is pretty much the same thing as a cursor. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: @René why would you say this is the best solution?  If going with a tally table I would use Sean's view or even better a materialized tally table.  If using a recursive cte why use a tally table at all when you can get the actual datetime for comparison?  but there are many ways to skin a cat and if you like this way go for it.