# How do I can divide a day in 30 minutes intervals in SQL server for a single date or multiple days like a month

Tags: sql-server

I have to divide 24 hours of a date into 48 intervals of 30 minutes each and need to get number of transaction happen in every interval

I am using b.entry_date_time BETWEEN '2019-04-14 14:00:01' AND '2019-04-14 14:30:00' to get 30 minute interval but I want this for whole day when I will provide date as 2019-04-14

```
SELECT b.store_no,
       CONVERT(varchar(10), b.transaction_date, 103) AS trans_date,
       CONVERT(varchar(8), b.entry_date_time, 108) AS Interval_start_time,
       COUNT(DISTINCT (a.transaction_id)) AS Sales_trans_count,
       SUM(a.gross_line_amount - a.pos_discount_amount) AS Sales_gross_total,
       COUNT(a.transaction_id) AS Sales_unit
FROM transaction_line AS a
     JOIN transaction_header AS b ON a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
WHERE line_object_type = 1
  AND line_object = 9008
  AND line_action = 1
  AND (b.entry_date_time BETWEEN '2019-04-14 14:00:01' AND '2019-04-14 14:30:00')
GROUP BY b.store_no,
         b.transaction_date;


store_no trans_date Interval_start_time Sales_trans_count Sales_gross_total Sales_unit
12    14/04/2019    14:00               3                485           3
18    14/04/2019    14:00               2                680           3
21    14/04/2019    14:00               7                535.15        13
44    14/04/2019    14:00               9                984.46        24
47    14/04/2019    14:00               5                577.47        11
50    14/04/2019    14:00               5                537.41        10
53    14/04/2019    14:00              12                1557.48       22
```

Interval_start_time is expected as given but not able to get it and as per requirement 24 hours should be decided int 30 minutes interval so i can get above result as expected.

Comment: Comments is not the right place for sample dataexpected results, as we can't read it (as it can't be formatted), Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55725840/edit) your question and post in as formated `text`. Thanks!

Comment: You need a table of dates (a calendar table).

Comment: I personally recommend Sean's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40408610/3484879).